# how to restore data from appWidgetProvider when reboot the phone?

Tags: android

i'm making a simple memo widget app.
just writing some texts and save it to SharedPreference.
everything is okay..
but when my phone is reboot, app widget is turned to be default.

I heard i should do something about Boot_Complete..
so I add Boot_Complete Permission and Intent-Filter in Manifest.
but i have no idea how i can call the onUpdate when my phone is reboot.
my source is this..
please see the onReceive part..

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++){
        int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAppPostItActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("widgetId", widgetId);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, widgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews remote = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        remote.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout, pending);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remote);

    }

}//onUpdate

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
        //I guess I should Call the onUpdate In here!! But I don't know how..
    }


}
```

after boot_complete, how can i restore my widget's data?
I hope any suggestion or clue or samples..
thanks a lot~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself.
i forgot to setText in onUpdate Method.
after add setText in onUpdate, it's working okay after reboot.